# auto increment Id generator in firebase real-time database

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm using firebase real-time database with express.js as backend.
Here's my data saving snippet code:

```
const db = require('./firebase_connection').firebaseDatabase

async function saveData(req, model) {
    await db.ref(model).set(req)
    return {"statusCode": "201", "message": "Inserted successfully"}
}

module.exports = { saveData }
```

This is the json output:

```
{
  "user" : {
    "email" : "TEST77@TEST.com",
    "full_name" : "Hossein Heydari",
    "password" : "test",
    "phone_number" : 54,
    "role" : "client"
  }
}
```

But I also need an Id added to database automatically, just like what `MongoDB` has which is `_id`

I need firebase to store data with a auto increment Id for any model, what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, firebase does provide a way to get the unique key when you push the changes, I am not sure if you have tried this:

```
postsRef.push({
  author: "gracehop",
  title: "Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
});

// Generate a reference to a new location and add some data using push()
var newPostRef = postsRef.push();

// Get the unique key generated by push()
var postId = newPostRef.key;
```

You can check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push) for more details.

Or, if you want to create similar what Mongo does then you should create a custom one, create a similar key like Mongo does and keep it in the DB and on every new insert add that ID to the model. You can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593337/is-there-any-way-to-create-mongodb-like-id-strings-without-mongodb).