# Generate Mongoose ObjectId in NextJs Frontend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am trying to generate Mongoose compliant ObjectId's on a NextJs frontend. The thing is though, the minute you import mongoose to try use the good-ol' `const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;` then `const _id = new ObjectId();` 'maneuver' it immediately throws a `TypeError: t.versions.node is undefined` error in my case (very hard to debug the first time.. I was optimist it would work maybe this time doing some refactoring a few months later... But the minute I tried like oil in water.).

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
// and
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Give the same error.

Is there a better way to create it? Other systems rely on this being a valid Id i.e. not just the same alphaNumeric length.

Less of a performance hit than creating a NextJs API GET route that just returns my backend shenanigans as a simple string (a network request?).

P.S. Use TypeScript if that could mean anything.. Also using Vercel (which has also caused build problems in the past)

Comment: Yes, I am aware that the issue is that node is note exactly available on a frontend browser. Just asking for workarounds, help, or advice.

Answer (score 0):

I was too stuck in looking for a NextJs solution in my searches when it is still Javascript and React at the end of the day. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593337/is-there-any-way-to-create-mongodb-like-id-strings-without-mongodb) had the answer:

`npm i bson`

then

```
import { ObjectId } from 'bson';

const id  = new ObjectId();
```

Works perfectly in Next.js as well as my Mongo database / Mongoose.